# What anime is this grey-haired character from?

Tags: yosuga-no-sora

[image]

Does anyone know which anime this character is from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as apart of the phase out of image only id requests. [Meta for further reading](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2736/1587)

Answer (score 7):

The name of this anime is [Yosuga no Sora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosuga_no_Sora):

[image]

> Yosuga no Sora (ヨスガノソラ?, lit. Sky of Connection) is a Japanese
> romance/drama adult visual novel developed by CUFFS ("Sphere"). The
> game was originally released for Windows PC on December 5, 2008. It
> was adapted into a serialized manga and an anime TV series. A
> sequel/fan disk titled Haruka na Sora was released later on October
> 24, 2009, which contains new and expanded scenarios for several
> characters from the original game.

## Plot

> Haruka Kasugano and his twin sister Sora have lost both their parents
> in an accident, and with them all their support. They decide to move
> out of the city to the rural town where they once spent summers with
> their late grandfather. At first everything seems familiar and
> peaceful, but changes come as Haruka starts to remember things from
> his youth.

Read more [here.](http://myanimelist.net/anime/8861/Yosuga_no_Sora:_In_Solitude_Where_We_Are_Least_Alone.#iduXmOt3Klom1Zdv.99)

The guy in the image is [Haruka Kasugano](http://myanimelist.net/character/33225/Haruka_Kasugano):

[image]

This image is larger comparing to the one you post in you question:

[image]

Their hair look the same in both pictures, so I think this is the anime you are looking for.

Comment: at first I was like - "looks like Saika Totsuka from OreGairu". But then I remembered - "Oh gawd, I know this sick dude". And then this answer was posted. Sigh, a few minutes late.